# Split a .txt at each period instead of by line?

Tags: python, list, split

I am attempting to split a .txt file by sentence into a list, but my coding efforts can only split by line.

Example of .txt contents:

```
This is line 1 of txt file,
it is now on line 2. Here is the
second sentence between line 2 and 3.
```

Code

```
listed = []
with open("example.txt","r") as text:
    Line = text.readline()


while Line!="":
  Line1 = Line.split(".")
  for sentence in Line1:
    listed.append(sentence)
  Line = text.readline()


print(listed)
```

This would print something like: `['This is line 1 of txt file,\n','it is now on line 2\n', 'Here is the\n','second sentence between line 2 and 3/n']`

If the entire document was on one line, this would work correctly, except for cases like "Mr." and "Mrs." and such. However, that's a future worry. Does anyone out there know how to use split in the above scenario?

Comment: The simplest way is `text.read().split('.')`.

Comment: Just tried this, but I get this error message: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Are you sure you used `.read()` and not `.readlines()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming **all** sentence ends with a dot `.`*

---

You may just :

- read the whole file : `fic.read()`
- remove return char `replace('\n', '')`
- split on dot
- apply `strip` on each sentence to remove spaces padding and leading spaces
- keep the sentences

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as fic:
    content = fic.read().replace('\n', '')
sentences = list(map(str.strip, content.split(".")))
```

---

A version more detailled

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as fic:
    content = fic.read()

content = content.replace('\n', '')
sentences = content.split(".")
sentences = list(map(str.strip, sentences))
#  same as
sentences = [s.strip() for s in sentences]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Azro! I've been fighting that same problem for a week. I now understand the difference between .read() and .readline() Edit: I am very new to python, and you really helped me at a roadblock. Thank you to everyone; my brain is exploding, but this really helps.

Comment: Why remove the newlines? They’re part of the text, after all.

Comment: @AJDouglas ;) You can now think about accepting the answer; and vote up if you want ;)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile the OP asked for sentences, you don't need to know on which line they were to do so

Comment: Aha, just learned about the check mark below the upvote area. Rather odd spot for new users. I gave you an upvote, but Stack Overflow says users with less than 15 rep can't upvote.

Answer (score 0):

split on a string will split on whatever you ask it to, without regard to line breaks, just do read to pull the whole file instead of readlines.  the issue becomes whether that's too much text to handle in a single read, if so you'll need to be more clever. you'll probably want to filter out actual line breaks to get the effect of one-string-per-sentence.